# Are LaTeX3 regular expressions able to match characters at the start of a line?

Tags: expl3, l3regex

---

I would like to use LaTeX3 regular expressions to extract the "lines" from text like the following:

```
- First line
- second line ending with \LaTeX
- third line with - in the middle
- fourth line that
goes on for a bit
```

By a "line" I mean text that starts with a dash `-` that occurs at the beginning of a "physical line", and then continues until the next such dash, or the end of the string.

My first guess was that something like the following would work:

```
\regex_split:nVN {  [\f\n\r]\s+-\s+  } { \Lines } \l_tmp_seq
```

My understanding is that this should match a "newline character" followed by `-` that is surrounded by white-space on both sides. Unfortunately, this fails horribly, producing only one match:

[image]

As this didn't work I thought that I would try a very simple-minded approach and just split the string on white-space surrounded dashes `-`. This would give the wrong result on lines like the third line above, but I can use `--` in the middle of the line so this is a workable alternative. As `\s` matches white space, the following should split lines on `-`:

```
\regex_split:nVN { \s+-\s+  } { \Lines } \l_tmp_seq
```

This is better, but the results are still not perfect because, in addition to the expected problem on line 3, having `\LateX` at the end of a line confuses `\regex_split` presumably because macros tends to swallow spaces:

[image]

The best solution that I have found is using:

```
\regex_split:nVN { \B-\B } { \Lines } \l_tmp_seq
```

This produces the output that I was expecting from the last regex:

[image]

That is, we are getting an unwanted match for the `-` in the middle of the third line but this is otherwise OK.

**Question** Is there a regular expression that does not return any false matches? Initial and/or final matching empty sequences are allowed.

[Aside: I am not worried about the "empty" initial sequences above because I know that can get rid of them using

```
\seq_pop_left:NN \l_tmp_seq \l_tmpa_tl % pop initial blank
```

Terminating empty sequences can, of course, be dealt with in almost exactly the same way using `\seq_pop_right:NN`.]

Here is a full MWE to produce the examples above:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\parindent=0pt

\newcommand\BS{$\backslash$}
\newcommand\Test[1]{\textbf{Testing:}\quad\texttt{#1}}
\begin{document}

\newcommand\Lines{
    - First line
    - second line ending with \LaTeX
    - third line with -- in the middle
    - fourth line that
    goes on for a bit
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_tmp_seq
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_split:nnN { nVN }

\Test{[\BS f\BS n\BS r]\BS s+-\BS s+}
\regex_split:nVN { [\f\n\r]\s+-\s+  } { \Lines } \l_tmp_seq
\begin{itemize}\item\seq_use:Nn \l_tmp_seq {\item }\end{itemize}

\Test{\BS s-\BS s}
\regex_split:nVN { \s-\s  } { \Lines } \l_tmp_seq
\begin{itemize}\item\seq_use:Nn \l_tmp_seq {\item }\end{itemize}

\Test{\BS B-\BS B}
\regex_split:nVN { \B-\B  } { \Lines } \l_tmp_seq
\begin{itemize}\item\seq_use:Nn \l_tmp_seq {\item }\end{itemize}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Escaping the `-` in the regular expressions doesn't help either.

Finally, the problem may be that the newline characters in `\Lines` are stripped when it is defined. As far as I can see this is OK because the code above gives similar output. In particular, if I use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\parindent=0pt

\begingroup\obeylines
\gdef\Lines{
    - First line
    - second line ending with \LaTeX
    - third line with -- in the middle
    - third line that
    goes on for a bit
}
\endgroup

\begin{document}

  \ExplSyntaxOn
  \seq_new:N \l_tmp_seq
  \cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_split:nnN { nVN }
  \regex_split:nVN { [\f\n\r]\s+\-\s+  } { \Lines } \l_tmp_seq

  Sequence~length:~ \seq_count:N \l_tmp_seq.
  \begin{itemize}\item\seq_use:Nn \l_tmp_seq {\item }\end{itemize}
  \ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

then I get the output:

[image]

In practice, I am getting `\Lines` as the `\BODY` of a [environ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ) environment, so I don't really have the luxury of this definition...

Comment: The problem is certainly that newline chararacters are converted to spaces, and with \obeylines I get correct splitted results.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Looks like an answer to me!

Comment: @Andrew: well I'm sure that \obeylines or something equivalent is needed, I'm not sure that your regex is completly correct but will check again later.

Comment: @Andrew To TeX's eyes, `abc<newline>def` and `abc def` are exactly the same after the input has been tokenized, assuming standard category codes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need obeylines or something equivalent so that the newline char doesn't disappear. The following splits the lines (nearly) as wanted. Instead of `\^^M` one can also use `\r` (I only used the first because `\show\Lines` showed `^^M`).

This creates this sequence:

```
The sequence \l_tmp_seq contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {First line}
>  {second line ending with \LaTeX }
>  {third line with -- in the middle}
>  {fourth line that^^Mgoes on for a bit^^M}.
<recently read> }
```

One problem could be that the fourth item contains a `^^M` and so a probably unwanted line break.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\parindent=0pt

\newcommand\BS{$\backslash$}
\newcommand\Test[1]{\textbf{Testing:}\quad\texttt{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begingroup
\obeylines
\gdef\Lines{
    - First line
    - second line ending with \LaTeX
    - third line with -- in the middle
    - fourth line that
    goes on for a bit
}

\endgroup

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_tmp_seq
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \regex_split:nnN { nVN }

\Test{}\verb+^^M\-+
\regex_replace_once:nnN { \A\^^M?\-\s* } {} \Lines %to get rid of the first ^^M
\regex_split:nVN { \^^M\-\s* } \Lines \l_tmp_seq

\begin{itemize}\item\seq_use:Nn \l_tmp_seq {\item }\end{itemize}


\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can remove the initial hyphen and the possible `^^M` by first doing `\regex_replace_once:nnN { \A\^^M?\-\s* } {} \Lines`; for the splitting you can do `\regex_split:nVN { \^^M\-\s* } \Lines \l_tmp_seq` and also the initial space will vanish. Note that `\Lines` should not be braced: the argument type `V` denotes a single token.

Comment: @Andrew TeX works with tokens; during tokenization, end-of-lines are discarded and (usually) substituted with something else (normally a space).

Comment: ^^M, ^^J are tex specialities, ^^M is ASCII 13 (return).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer By the way, you *can* use `\r` instead of `\^^M` in the search regex.

Comment: Is there a description somewhere of `^^M`, `^^J`, `^^K`, etc? I just did a quick google search and didn't find anything.

Comment: Hmm, it seems that the main problem with my regex, when I tested it with `\obeylines`, is that I *required* white space before the `-` with `[\r\n]\s+\-\s+` (note the `\s+\-`), whereas by default the spaces are gobbled so I should have used `[\r\n]\s*\-\s+`. If I instead use `\obeylines` *and* `\obeyspaces` then this is of course OK.

Comment: @egreg thanks for the corrections. I edited the answer.

Comment: @Andrew yes, spaces at the begin of lines are gobbled (my regex skills are a bit sketchy so I didn't really realize what the \s+ is doing).

Comment: My regex skills are OK but it seems my tex skills may be sketchy:) Thank you, I've learned a lot about regular expressions in latex from this!